# How to timestamp Each Field Updated in another assigned Field Ms Access

Tags: vba, ms-access-2013

I'm setting up a database to monitor/timestamp the time of edit for each field (not just the form). so entered the following code in the "after update" event of the property:

```
Private Sub DReceived_AfterUpdate()
    Me![CLASS] = Now()
End Sub
```

I had hoped that the edit of the field labeled "CLASS" would timestamp in the field `"DReceived"` but that is not happening.

I have tried `"now()"` function in the property of the table field but it keeps fixing the current time and date even without anything update. (I ONLY WANT A TIMESTAMP WHEN DATE In Any Field is updated

```
Private Sub DReceived_AfterUpdate()
    Me![CLASS] = Now()
End Sub
```

If I have fields A to F in a table, if I edit A, B should Timestamp, C; D should TimeStamp, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [Before Change Data Macro](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/before-change-macro-event), not a VBA sub on a form. For one, subs won't trigger if one directly edits the table, and data macros are intended primarily to do this.

The macro would incorporate logic like:

```
If Updated("CLASS") Then
    SetField
        DReceived
        =Now()
```